# ActiveRecord в массив

Tags: yii2, activerecord

Как конвертировать объект ActiveRecord в массив? В ActiveQuery это делается просто (`User::find()->asArray()->one()`), но как преобразовать уже существующий AR в массив?

PS: это перевод вопроса [Yii2 - ActiveRecord to Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31125334/yii2-activerecord-to-array) с оригинального SO

Comment: ActiveRecord наследует интерфейс ArrayAccess что обеспечивает возможность работы с моделью, как с массивом. Не плохо бы уточнить для чего вам необходимо получить массив из модели, тогда ответ может быть более точным.

Comment: Честно говоря я сделал перевод вопроса с оригинального SO. Вижу что забыл сделать пометку (сейчас это исправлю). Как мне показалось, это довольно интересный и необычный вопрос. В оригинальном вопросе пользователь спрашивал с целью кэширования объекта AR

Answer (score 1):

В документации есть класс [ArrayHelper](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-array.html)

```
$posts = Post::find()->limit(10)->all();
    $data = ArrayHelper::toArray($posts, [
        'app\models\Post' => [
            'id',
            'title',
            // the key name in array result => property name
            'createTime' => 'created_at',
            // the key name in array result => anonymous function
            'length' => function ($post) {
                return strlen($post->content);
            },
        ],
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну или так:

`ArrayHelper::map(Post::find()->all(), 'id', 'field_name');`

также загляните сюда [доки yii2 (ArrayHelper)](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-array.html)